# Connecting PHP with MySQL DB in XAMPP issues

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect my PHP to my XAMPP DB server, but as it seems I'm not doing something right.
This is my code:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$db=  "blogdata";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

And it returns:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\KungFu\Blog.php on line 8
>   Connection failed: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I think everything is correct, tried different variations but as you can tell it is not working.

Comment: Using your username/password details, are you able to log into phpmyadmin?
Did you create this new user profile in mysql too? Sorry might sound like a dumb question here. Maybe reset the password via phpmyadmin.

Comment: Ahh did you assign the database to this username?

Comment: I am using XAMMP, therefor i never set a username or pass, its the default

Comment: Ok so with that username and password, can you access PHPmyadmin then?

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)

Comment: I am sayin that i use XAMMP, which means i dont log in, the software does it, i only press admin

Answer (score -2):

Best way to connect php to MySQL is to use new method : PDO :)

PHP :
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');

Comment: ok, thanks, but in this case i want to use the MySQLi package, and do you have any idea to fix it ?